# A question about the ring of integers and the coefficients

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

Let $F,F(x)$ be number fields, and the ring of integers of $F$ be $A$, the ring of integers of $F(x)$ be $B$. $f(y)$ is the minimal polynomial of $x$ over $F$, with $f(y)=(y-x)h(y)$, s.t. $h(y)=a_0+a_1y+...a_{n-1}y^{n-1}$. If $x\in B$, then how to see the $a_i$ are in $B$?

Comment: Since $x$ is integral over $F$, it follows that $f(y)$ has coefficients in $A$. Then, using long division$\,-\,$dividing $f(y)$ by $(y-x)$, the fact that $x \in B$ implies that all terms of the quotient have coefficients in $B$.

Comment: @quasi Thank you, but why it follows that $f(y)$ has coefficients in $A$?

Comment: Actually, I'm not sure -- I'll let someone else take over.

Comment: @quasi thank you anyway

Comment: No problem (and sorry for any confusion I caused). Also, I'm not sure that $f$ does have coefficients in $A$. But the long division argument would still work provided $f$ has coefficients in $B$.

Comment: @quasi sorry I can't see why the fact $x\in B$ implies all terms of the quotient have the coefficients in $B$. Indeed, $h(x)=f'(x)$, thus they should be in $F$.

Comment: Why do you say $h(x)=f'(x)$? How does the derivative come into play?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55104/discussion-between-danny-and-quasi).

Comment: If you're going to post two closely related questions, you should link each one to the other: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2176180/two-questions-involving-field-extension-and-ring-of-integers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $x$ is an algebraic integer, there exists a monic, irreducible polynomial $p$ in $\mathbb{Z}[y]$ such that $p(x) = 0$.

Since $p \in \mathbb{Z}[y]$, $p$ is also in $F[y]$.

Then, since $f(y)$ is the minimal polynomial for $x$ over $F$, it follows that $f$ divides $p$ in $F[y]$, hence $f$ also divides $p$ in $\mathbb{C}[y]$.

Let $f(y) = (y - x_1)\cdots (y-x_n)$ be the complete factorization of $f$ in $\mathbb{C}[y]$.

Then $x_1,...,x_n$ are also roots of $p$, hence $x_1,...,x_n$ are algebraic integers.

It follows that all coefficients of $f(y)$ are algebraic integers. Then since

- $F$ is the field of fractions of $A$

  $A$ is integrally closed

  $f \in F[y]$

it follows that $f \in A[y]$, hence, since $A \subseteq B$, we also have $f \in B[y]$.

Let $K = F(x)$.

Then since

- $f \in B[y]$

  $y-x \in B[y]$, with $y - x$ monic

  $f(y) = (y-x)h(y)$

it follows, by polynomial long division in $K[y]$, that $h(y) \in B[y]$.

Thus, all coefficients of $h$ are in $B$, as was to be shown.

Comment: Thank u, but I think $F$ is not necessarily contained in $\mathbb{C}$, thus you may not have $f$ divided $p$ in $\mathbb{C}[y]$. And I can't see why $f\in A[y]$.

Comment: You said that $F$ and $F(x)$ are number fields. That terminology implies that they are subfields of the algebraic closure of $\mathbb{Q}$, and hence are also subfields of $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: As to your question: "why $f \in A[y]$?", we know $f \in F[y]$, and each linear factor $(y-x_k)$ of $f$ has algebraic integer coeffs. Thus, expanding the product of those $n$ factors, the coeffs of $f$ are algebraic integers, but also elements of $F$. Since $A = O_F$, it follows that $A$ is integrally closed, and since $A$ is integrally closed, any algebraic integers in $F$ must be in $A$. Thus, $f \in A[y]$.